# Basic Input assembly Language

Tags: assembly, input, masm

Hey I have started learning `assembly language`.

**I wrote the following code:**

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000H
.DATA
MSG db "Hey$"
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV AH,0AH ; setting the sub function
    MOV DX, offset msg ; moving address of msg to dx
    INT 21h     ; calling interrupt

    MOV AH, 09
    MOV DX, OFFSET MSG
    INT 21h     ; for printing

    MOV AH, 04Ch    ; Select exit function
    MOV AL, 00  ; Return 0
    INT 21h     ; Call Interupt to Terminate program
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I am trying to take input, it is working kind of but when I try printing it I do not get the proper string. I used this [list](http://www.skynet.ie/%7Edarkstar/assembler/intlist.html) to select the interrupt function.

I am attaching a screenshot, I have given input the following string:

```
Hey this is me taking input
```

But I got unexpected result.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

## Questions:

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Is there a nice debugger to use when writing assembly programs?
- Any links to good assembly tutorials would be very nice?

Thanks.

Comment: `0a` returns a buffer of the input. byte 0 = max chars buffer can hold, byte 1 = number of chars from last input, bytes 2+ = actual chars. You're just dumping the entire buffer, including the metadata bytes.

Comment: How can I acess by 0 and byte 1 and byte 2+ seperately?

Comment: just use offset msg + 2, basically

Comment: @MarcB I am using `offset msg + 2` but still getting unexpected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set aside enough space for your input string; when you "declared" `MSG`, you gave it room for only 4 characters (`"Hey$"`).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.skynet.ie/~darkstar/assembler/intlist.html

Note: With "db Size dup (0)" we can occupy the value of Size amount of bytes.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 10H
Size = 3
.DATA
M1  db Size           ; First character=max length
M2  db ?              ; Second char of buffer=length of input
MSG db Size dup (20H) ; Rest of buffer=input string
    db 0DH            ; followed by carriage return (0Dh)
;---
    db "$"            ; (allways needed for printing function)
.CODE
MAIN PROC
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX

MOV AH,0AH        ; setting the sub function
MOV DX, offset M1 ; moving address of input buffer
INT 21h           ; calling interrupt

MOV AH, 09
MOV DX, OFFSET MSG
INT 21h           ; for printing

MOV AH, 04CH      ; Select exit function
MOV AL, 00        ; Return 0
INT 21h           ; Call Interupt to Terminate program
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```